# Different from x Different to x Different than

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, word-usage, conjunctions

In the following sentence:

> "When I visited my old school after so many years, it looked completely different in the classrooms and the backyard /from what/to what/than/ it had been when I was a little boy.">

Are the three options acceptable in spoken English ?

Answer (score 2):

Fowler's *Modern English Usage* endorses "different from," "different than," and "different to," pointing to examples of each cited in the *OED* dating back to 1590, 1644, and 1526 respectively.   I think, however, that "different to" is apt to sound strange to most native speakers of American English.   Preceding a clause, I'd use "different than."   In your example, the most natural sounding option (to me) is: "... the classrooms and backyard looked completely different than when I was a little boy," or perhaps "... the classrooms and backyard looked completely different than I remember them from my childhood."

Answer (score 1):

I'm an American and I hear *from* and *than* equally often. To my ear, *different to* is a solely British usage, I don't think I've ever heard an American use it.

Comment: My question is "Is it acceptable in spoken English" and by that I mean "Is it considered good English when spoken ?  I question this specifically about "than" because it isn't a preposition.

Comment: *than* isn't technically a preposition, but it often serves as one in informal communication. So in my opinion it isn't good English, but it is acceptable English.