# Is "different from" or "different than" more correct?

Tags: word-choice

"I am different from/than you." (I am not similar to you.)

Is one usage more correct than the other? Or are they two different usages that could mean two different things?

The answers to the other question cited describe the *history* of the expressions"different from" and "different than," but not the differences in *meaning.*

I believe that Nanigashi's and Andrew Leach's comments most nearly approximate the correct answer.

Comment: Given your alternate text ("I am not similar to you."), why not "I am different to you"?

Comment: @KillingTime: I was taught: "I am different from you." The from puts the distance. "To" moves one closer.

Comment: In American English, "different from" is correct, while "different than" is considered incorrect n a case like this, though many people use it. In my experience, Americans never say "different to" unless they are trying to sound British or have adopted British speech patterns as a result of living in the UK or among Brits elsewhere.

Comment: Different *from* is correct, you would use *than* in a comparative sentence...more different than...

Comment: There exists an adjective which is, in some sense, intrinsically comparative, namely **different**. In some dialects, this adjective can take a than clause: *John is different than I thought*...

Comment: ... But even in those dialects in which different prohibits a than clause, it still shares properties with compared rather than simple adjectives, Joan W Bresnan says in [Syntax of the Comparative Clause Construction in English](https://www.google.ro/search?q=Syntax+of+the+Comparative+Clause+Construction+in+English&oq=Syntax+of+the+Comparative+Clause+Construction+in+English&aqs=chrome..69i57.2583j0j8&client=tablet-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgdii).

Comment: In British English, *different from* is more correct than *different to* — similar to; different from. *Different than* is non-standard. I think it's going to be difficult to identify "more correct" given that that judgement may be different in different dialects.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I know that is what it says in the OED (It actually says "different from" is "more accepted" - not "more correct") but I remain sceptical. "Different to" sounds more acceptable to my, admittedly rather aged, ear. And like Nanigashi, above I associate "different than" with Americans. Sometimes you just have that feeling that the OED have got it wrong - which I suppose is not inconceivable.

Comment: This question already has an answer here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382004/history-of-different-from-different-to-different-than and here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516/which-is-correct-is-different-from-or-is-different-than and here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183169/different-from-x-different-to-x-different-than